# How can I construct a grammar that generates this language?

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, automata

I'm studying for a finite automata & grammars test and I'm stuck with this question:

```
Construct a grammar that generates L:
L = {a^n b^m c^m+n|n>=0, m>=0}
```

I believe my productions should go along this lines:

```
    S->aA | aB
    B->bB | bC
    C->cC | c Here's where I have doubts
```

How can my production for C remember the numbers of m and n? I'm guessing this must rather be a context-free grammar, if so, how should it be?

Comment: If it had been homework I would have marked it, like I said, I'm studying for a test. I'm taking away the homework tag. Man, Homework != Test

Comment: Why so defensive on the homework tag? Studying for a test sounds like homework or at least "schoolwork" & the tag helps people looking for such questions find this one.

Comment: Actually it's the "finite automata & grammars" part that sounds like homework. Doesn't matter if it's for a test or not.

Comment: people looking for this question would look for "automata", "language" or "grammar" not "homework". Since I'm not asking you to do my homework it would be both a misplaced and meaningless tag.

Comment: Shouldn't such questions be migrated to Theoretical Computer Science?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like it should be like:

```
A->aAc | aBc | ac | epsilon
B->bBc | bc | epsilon
```

You need to force C'c to be counted during construction process. In order to show it's context-free, I would consider to use [Pump Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages).

Comment: I may be confusing some definition, but since the production rules all have only a single nonterminal on the left side, isn't this trivially a context-free grammar?

Comment: Actually, since m and n just need to be >= 0, your grammar is slightly incorrect.  Here's one that works:

A->aAc | B
B->bBc | (epsilon)

Comment: I guess the `ac` and `bc` parts are redundant. `ac` can be constructed by `aAc -> a epsilon c -> ac` and the same goes for `bc`.

Answer (score 4):

```
S -> X
X -> aXc | Y
Y -> bYc | e
```

where `e == epsilon` and `X` is unnecessary but
added for clarity

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this does sound like homework, but a hint:

Every time you match an 'a',  you must match a 'c'. Same for matching a 'b'.

Comment: Thanks. That 'hint' is actually the answer. And no, it's not homework.

Answer (score 0):

S->aSc|A
A->bAc|λ

This means when ever you get a at least you have 1 c or if you get a and b you must have 2 c.
i hope it has been helpful

Answer (score 0):

Well guys, this is how I'll do it:

```
P={S::=X|epsilon,
   X::=aXc|M|epsilon,
   M::=bMc|epsilon}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer:

S -> aAc | aSc

A -> bc | bAc

where S is the start symbol.

Answer (score 0):

L = {epsilon, ac, bc, abcc, abbccc, aabbcccc,.....}

We can try to increase c every time either a or b is increased.

S -> aSc|bSc|epsilon

Answer (score -1):

S-> aBc/epsilon
B-> bBc/S/epsilon
This takes care of the order of the alphabets as well